# ESLint error no-unneeded-ternary

Tags: javascript, eslint

ESLint is telling me this error message inside my JS module: ***error  no-unneeded-ternary  Unnecessary use of conditional expression for default assignment***

The error comes in the `get` method on the `return` statement `return val ? val : defaultVal;`?

```
import ls from 'local-storage';

export default {
    get(key, defaultVal = null) {
        var val = ls(key);
        return val ? val : defaultVal;
    },

    set(key, val) {
        return ls(key, val);
    },

    remove(key) {
        return ls.remove(key);
    },
};
```

Any idea why do I get this error message? I have found some resource on ESLint's website regarding this error message [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary) but it applies to boolean expressions and I can not figure out why would that apply to my code...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You don't need a ternary when a simple `val || defaultVal` will do.

Comment: @UmakantPatil Those aren't equivalent.

Comment: @UmakantPatil Once you make them actually do the same thing the differences are (a) browser-dependent, and (b) within 1-3%. It's also shorter and clearer; unless you're in a very tight game loop or similar it's a pointless micro-optimization. In any case, the original question was regarding the ESLint warning which defaults to flagging ternaries in default value assignments. ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Oh right. my bad. I didn't do the assignments in one case. Thanks!

Comment: Is using a `??` over `||` a better practice?

Comment: @TanishqVyas :shrug: `??` wasn’t a useful option when the answer was written. I’d say `??` is likely better but I usually forget it’s there :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the reply. I wanted to know about a better practice since `??` would check for nullish values whereas `||` may also trigger when the value is falsy. So, as per the case it should boil down to choosing between nullish or falsy values right? Please correct me if I have a wrong understanding.

Answer (score 20):

```
// Bad
foo(bar ? bar : 1);

// Good
foo(bar || 1);
```

This is how they say in Es-lint