# error Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression no-unneeded-ternary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, atom-editor, ternary-operator, eslint

I am trying this [code](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-Show-Hide-Toggle-HTML-DIV-on-Button-click-using-ng-show-and-ng-hide.aspx) in [atom](https://atom.io/) with [ESLint](http://eslint.org/)

Code snippet:

```
$scope.IsVisible = false;
$scope.ShowHide = function () {
  $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true; // error
};
```

Got this ESLint error:
error Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression  no-unneeded-ternary

Tried with these solutions [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702328/eslint-error-no-unneeded-ternary) and [solution 2](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary), but error is not fixed. Furthermore, [code](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AngularJS-Show-Hide-Toggle-HTML-DIV-on-Button-click-using-ng-show-and-ng-hide.aspx) works fine in editor without ESLint.

Comment: `$scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible;`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the good way =). No need to use statements in this case.

```
$scope.IsVisible = !$scope.IsVisible;
```

Comment: If, like me, you need to check for a `true` value, use the double bang: `!!$scope.IsVisible`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I wanted to assign a value to my boolean, according to a variable that was either an object or null.

As [kylesimmonds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766334/kylesimmonds) stated, the double bang `!!` operator can be used.

```
const myObject: SomeObjectType | null;
...

const isObjectExistent: boolean = !!myObject;
/*
  instead of:
  const isObjectExistent: boolean = myObject? true : false;
*/
```

Check: [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)